# Set record to dynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have some problem with Amazon DynamoDB, maybe someone explain me what I am doing wrong and what the way better. When I want to save data with my custom id to the table, it give me error like this

```
Failed saving item : User: arn:aws:sts::789096419101:assumed-role/zippz_unauth_MOBILEHUB_1029720639/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:789096419101:table/zippz-mobilehub-1029720639-user (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: O04JC7AH4CNREL2GFA6FQ20HJ3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

but when I set id with `awsMobileClient.getIdentityManager().getCachedUserID()`
everything is good. And my first question, how Can I save record with my Id? Because when I clear data in the app and login with the same user, Amazon SDK crete new record with identical data but different id.
My second question. I use scan to get date from table, but I dont want to fetch all record, only 50. I saw in the amazon doc method limit and try it, but it didn't work. my code

```
    final DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                    .withLimit(50);
PaginatedScanList<ProductDO> result = dynamoDBMapper.scan(ProductDO.class, scanExpression);
```

This code return all record. Could someone explain me this two problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The user-id field is configured in the way that only Cognito Identity Id can be used to store the record in the table. This way, every entry is mapped to the user and only the corresponding user can modify it or read it. Using custom id in this configuration is not possible because it would not have any mapping to the user whose data it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can I check is current user exist when someone enter twice?